# How to get Image Resource

Tags: android, imagebutton

How should I get current image resource of an imageButton?
I need something like this:

```
imageButton.getImageResource();
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need the image resource?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you can't, current API doesn't allow this.
But if you really need this, you can do something like this:

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_resource);
imageButton.setTag(R.drawable.your_resource);
//
// somewhere later...
//
Integer resource = (Integer)imageButton.getTag();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `imageButton.getDrawable()` to get the drawable of the ImageButton object and then use `setImageDrawable()` instead of `setImageResource()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_resource);
imageButton.setTag(R.drawable.your_resource);

Integer resource = (Integer) imageButton.getTag();

if(resource == R.drawable.your_resource){
    // do something
}else {
}
```

Comment: this is a duplicate answer