# ImageView has the setImageResource method. What is the getImageResource method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

Using intents to click on an element from the `RecyclerView`, with a small image on each element, to go to another screen/activity which will show the enlarge picture.

For example, `Textview` has `setText` and `getText`.

How about `ImageView`? They have `setImageResource` but I am trying to now get the image resource

Comment: what if you use imageButton?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370993/how-to-get-image-resource

Comment: If one of the answers has helped you solve your issue, please be sure to select it as the correct answer for anyone else who may have the same issue in the future. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no method that will give you `ImageResource`.

You can check **[ImageView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java)**. They just convert your ImageResource to Drawable and use it. So you have a getter method for Drawable `imageView.getDrawable();`. This is only what you can get. There is no getter for getting resource id from `Drawable` object.

> ```
>  if (mResource != 0) {
>             try {
>                 d = mContext.getDrawable(mResource);
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
>                 // Don't try again.
>                 mResource = 0;
>             }
>         }
> ```

**Solution 1** [From ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474954/6891563)

If you want pass Image to another Activity, you can do this.

When you set ImageView resource in Adapter then set a Tag on this.

```
imageView0.setTag(R.drawable.apple);
```

Now when you want get that id when user click, then only do

```
private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) {
    return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you are one setting ImageView resource, then you would have this resource integer in your List?, so when user click then get resource again like

```
yourList.get(getAdapterPosition).getImageId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set your first ImageView's tag to the resource id, and then retrieve it later with `getTag()` to set as the resource id of the new ImageView.

For instance:

```
//First set your original image tag...
ImageView original; //The original ImageVew
Integer resId = R.drawable.resource; //The original resource
original.setTag(resId); //Add your resource id to the tag

//Then, to get the resource id...
Integer resId = original.getTag();
```